# Daemon and non-daemon thread priority in Java

Tags: java, jvm

I know how the JVM treats daemon and non-daemon threads when the main thread terminates. I wonder if there is any difference in priority of daemon and non-daemon threads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there is no difference in priority between Daemon and non-daemon thread priority in Java, you can define priority or it will be inherited from parent

From JavaDoc :

> The priority of the newly created thread is set equal to the priority
>   of the thread creating it, that is, the currently running thread

[Oracle Java Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html)